# EWS Exchange request not responding

Tags: c#, .net, email, exchangewebservices

We are using the EWS Exchange webservice to read and send emails.

We noticed that after we have failed to send an email twice and after that tries to read emails the request to FindItems is not responding. No timeout no respond what so ever.

We fail to send the email do to that attachment could not be found on the path that was set.

So the problem is why doesn't the request timeout or respond.
Anyone have a clue.

UPDATE:
Tried some more and it seems that after 2 request that while cause an exception and then the third request just stops, no respond.
Is there a limit when requesting to Office365 how many failed request one can have or something like that?

The exception that occurs the two first times are but never happens the third time:
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.BuildEwsHttpWebRequest() | The request failed. Could not find file ''.
Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.BuildEwsHttpWebRequest()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ServiceRequestBase.ValidateAndEmitRequest(IEwsHttpWebRequest& request)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeService.InternalCreateItems(IEnumerable`1 items, FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode, ServiceErrorHandling errorHandling)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.Item.InternalCreate(FolderId parentFolderId, Nullable`1 messageDisposition, Nullable`1 sendInvitationsMode)
   at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage.InternalSend(FolderId parentFolderId, MessageDisposition messageDisposition)
   at EmailServer.MailServers.Exchange.ExchangeMailServer.SendMessage(IMailMessage message)